# Java Test метода, логика которого завязана на реальное время

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, время

Пишу web приложение на Java, использую Spring MVC, Hibernate, и у меня в коде есть метод, который выполняет одни действия если он вызван до 11 часов утра, и другие если после. Мне нужно реализовать тест этого метода. Вопрос в том как сделать тестирование не завязываясь на реальное время? Менять реальное системное время не вариант, как и подменять системную реализацию времени на свою для использования в коде метода. На данный момент я ввел в класс этого метода дополнительную публичную статическую переменную LocalTime, но это мне кажется не лучшим решением. Подскажите, какие есть ещё варианты реализовать @Test без изменения кода самого приложения?

Comment: мокирование смотрели?

Comment: Как писать МОК?

Comment: сделать переменную, с помощью которой будет получаться время либо сделать метод, потом замокать это дело и проверить работу с временем до 11 часов и после

Comment: Да, МОК, это то что надо, но как его правильно реализовать? Какую библиотеку лучше использовать? Пытался сделать мок на LocalTime.now() с помощью PowerMock, но не получается даже запустить тест. Ругается на @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)  : InvocationTargetException.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить Вам инжектить `LocalTime` в конструктор объекта, у которого вызывается тестируемый метод. При создании экземпляра Вы будете передавать на вход конструктору реальное время, а в тесте моки со временем <11 и >11.